# \u200c instead of real Half space

Tags: python

I am scraping some HTML pages with python. The text in some spaces has Half space character (\u200c). When i use the text in a variable, every things is OK. The problem is when i add the text to a list, it shows '\u200c' instead of real Half space. what is the problem?

Comment: I don't know what a "half space" is, but `'\u200c'` is (a different representation of) a normal unicode character, like `0x1` is a different representation of `1`. So I think your problem is likely not a problem at all, but it's hard to say without seeing any code.

Comment: See Here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm

Comment: Why do you refer to it as "half space"? The `\u200c` character is ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER.

Comment: based on Persian Wikipedia.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will show `'\u200c'` because it's what `__repr__`method gives you. However, try printing it using `print()` and you should get what you want, as `print()` uses the `__str__` magic method.

Comment: @keramat If the value is stored in the ith index, what does print(your_list[i]) give?

Comment: It prints Truly!

Comment: @keramat So what's the problem then?

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to print all the list not elements, it works but printing all the list not work truly.

Comment: @keramat Printing the list won't call __str__ on its elements, and if you want that to happen, you would have to create a custom list class with a custom behaviour which does exactly what you want. But I don't think you wanna do that if the representation to the developer is not a serious issue. At the end of the day, the end user will see the half space if print() is employed.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using python 2.7. Start using python 3 instead and these issues will go away. Python 2.7 needs to represent unicode characters that way to know that they are unicode characters. Whereas python 3 handles all string as unicode characters so you don't really have to worry about it as much.

Comment: Thanks, But I am using python 3.4.